# How to unload Traits from Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, traits, squeak, pharo

I'm quite sure I will not use Traits in my everyday work as developer. There is a script to remove Traits from a Squeak image:

http://installer.pbworks.com/w/page/19997785/UnloadTraits

but I've tested without success under

PharoCore 1.3 (problems installing Installer: ScriptLoader new installingInstaller)
Pharo 1.2 and PharoCore 1.2 (ProvidedSelectors and LocalSends not found)

There is any working script to unload traits from Pharo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily possible, because the system uses Traits itself. The removal-script was written for Squeak a long time ago and never worked in Pharo. It would certainly need to be re-implemented in Pharo. There was some discussion in the mailing-list about making traits optional recently, check the status there.

Comment: Thanks, could you comment what would be the main difficulty or limitation to make the above script work into Pharo?

Comment: One difficulty will be to fix all the tools and libraries that adopted (the presence of) traits. Furthermore, each method that the script patches has to be checked to avoid new bugs: the Pharo code evolved and changed significantly over the past years.